# Can't authorize Google Directory Admin API call

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to write a server process that calls the Google Directory Admin API to determine groups memberships for a given user in my domain.

With the following scope...

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly`

...this call works (returns a 200) in the API Playground:

`GET /admin/directory/v1/groups?userKey=my.user@mydomain.com HTTP/1.1`

However, I am unable to get authorization right outside of the playground.

I have done the following:

(1) Added "Admin SDK" to the "Enabled APIs" in Google Developers Console

(2) Created a "service account" for my app in Google Developers Console

(3) Checked "Enable Google Apps Domain-wide Delegation" for this service account

(4) Checked "Furnish a new private key" for this service account

(5) Downloaded the JSON credentials for this service account

(6) In "admin.google.com" --> Security --> Advanced Settings --> Authentication --> Manage API client access, I have added entered the (numeric) ClientID for my service account in the "Client Name" field, and entered the following scope in the "One or More API Scopes" field and pressed authorize:  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly`

However, with the following Ruby code, authorization fails (`Google::Apis::ClientError: forbidden: Not Authorized to access this resource/api`):

```
require 'google/apis/admin_directory_v1'
require 'googleauth'
ENV['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'secrets.json'
scope = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly' ]
authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scope)
service = Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1::DirectoryService.new
service.authorization = authorization
response = service.list_groups(user_key: 'my.user@mydomain.com, domain: "mydomain.com")
```

(irb session pasted below)

Note that the user and domain have been changed here for redaction purposes. Also note that additionally, if `domain` is not supplied, `Google::Apis::ClientError: notFound: Domain not found.` is thrown.

irb session is as follows:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'google/apis/admin_directory_v1'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'googleauth'
=> false
irb(main):003:0> ENV['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'secrets.json'
=> "secrets.json"
irb(main):004:0> scope = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly' ]
=> ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly"]
irb(main):005:0>  authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scope)
=> #<Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials:0x0000000238b1a0 @authorization_uri=nil, @token_credential_uri=#<Addressable::URI:0x11c55ec URI:https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token>, @client_id=nil, @client_secret=nil, @code=nil, @expires_at=nil, @expires_in=nil, @issued_at=nil, @issuer="service-acct-test@test-1186.iam.gserviceaccount.com", @password=nil, @principal=nil, @redirect_uri=nil, @scope=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly"], @state=nil, @username=nil, @expiry=60, @audience="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token", @signing_key=#<OpenSSL::PKey::RSA:0x0000000238b218>, @extension_parameters={}, @additional_parameters={}>
irb(main):006:0> service = Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1::DirectoryService.new
=> #<Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1::DirectoryService:0x000000023dbdd0 @root_url="https://www.googleapis.com/", @base_path="admin/directory/v1/", @upload_path="upload/admin/directory/v1/", @batch_path="batch", @client_options=#<struct Google::Apis::ClientOptions application_name="unknown", application_version="0.0.0", proxy_url=nil, use_net_http=false>, @request_options=#<struct Google::Apis::RequestOptions authorization=nil, retries=0, header=nil, timeout_sec=nil, open_timeout_sec=20>>
irb(main):007:0> service.authorization = authorization
=> #<Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials:0x0000000238b1a0 @authorization_uri=nil, @token_credential_uri=#<Addressable::URI:0x11c55ec URI:https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token>, @client_id=nil, @client_secret=nil, @code=nil, @expires_at=nil, @expires_in=nil, @issued_at=nil, @issuer="service-acct-test@test-1186.iam.gserviceaccount.com", @password=nil, @principal=nil, @redirect_uri=nil, @scope=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly"], @state=nil, @username=nil, @expiry=60, @audience="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token", @signing_key=#<OpenSSL::PKey::RSA:0x0000000238b218>, @extension_parameters={}, @additional_parameters={}>
irb(main):008:0> response = service.list_groups(user_key: 'my.user@mydomain.com, domain: "mydomain.com")
Google::Apis::ClientError: forbidden: Not Authorized to access this resource/api
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:202:in `check_status'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9/lib/google/apis/core/api_command.rb:103:in `check_status'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:170:in `process_response'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:275:in `execute_once'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:107:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:54:in `block in retriable'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `times'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `retriable'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:104:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:54:in `block in retriable'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `times'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `retriable'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:96:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9/lib/google/apis/core/base_service.rb:267:in `execute_or_queue_command'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9/generated/google/apis/admin_directory_v1/service.rb:943:in `list_groups'
    from (irb):8
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'irb(main):009:0>
```

Comment: I think you are not impersonating any user, specifically for this scenario, the admin. Check this documentation, the user you want to impersonate is set in the parameter 'sub': https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/auth/service-accounts

Comment: I actually thought of that and added this:        auth_client = authorization.dup
auth_client.sub = 'admin.user@mydomain.com'
service = Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1::DirectoryService.new
response = service.list_groups(user_key: 'my.user@mydomain.com', domain: 'mydomain.com') and that throws this error:  "Requested client not authorized."  Any ideas?

Comment: i'm wondering if this line is correct: service.list_groups(user_key: 'my.user@mydomain.com, domain: "mydomain.com")   ... after the my.user@mydomain.com the quotation is not closed

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a call to 
`authorization.fetch_access_token!`
before calling the service as described in the [API client docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/auth/service-accounts#authorizingrequests).